# Sudden drop in the reviews on Google Play Store .Not able to get the exact reason

Tags: android, review

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G073.png)I had previously 3.7 version of my app in production on play store and now i have rollout update as a 3.7.1 version but after the update there was as sudden drop in the reviews by 50% to 60%. After much googling i am unable to find the exact cause. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a site about programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following code for my app and it is working fine, I hope this can help you.

> Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" +
>   context.getPackageName());
>       Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
>       // To count with Play market backstack, After pressing back button, 
>       // to taken back to our application, we need to add following flags to intent.
>
> goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
>                       Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET |
>                       Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
>
> try {
>           startActivity(goToMarket);
>       } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
>           startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
>                   Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" +
>   context.getPackageName())));
>       }

This will launch the Play Store with your App & user can promptly review over there.
Make sure, you're popping up correctly the rate us task.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, I've already implemented the above code.
It is redirecting perfectly to the PlayStore, as I've tested it manually several times.
Any sort of help would be grateful from your side.
@katie